# Strtictly convex functional has unique minimizer on a convex set

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, functional-calculus

On page 8 of the book *Regularity of Free Boundaries in Obstacle-type Problems*, it considered a functional
$$J(u):=\int_D (|\nabla u|^2+2fu)\,dx \qquad D=B(0,1)$$
where $f\in L^\infty(D)$ is fixed. It is minimized over a set
$$S:=\{u\in W^{1,2}(D): u-g\in W^{1,2}_0(D), u\ge \psi\text{ in }D\}$$
Here, $g,\psi\in L^\infty(D)$.

The author then stated, *"Since $J$ is continuous and strictly convex on a convex subset $S$ of the
Hilbert space $W^{1,2}(D)$, it has a unique minimizer on $S$."*

I am able to show that $J$ is continuous and strictly convex, and that $S$ is a convex subset. In addition, if a minimizer exists, it must be unique due to strict convexity. **However, how can I show the existence of a minimizer?**

---

My attempt: If $J$ satisfies

1. $\displaystyle\lim_{||u||_{W^{1,2}(D)}\to\infty}|J(u)|=+\infty$
2. $J(u)$ is lower bounded on $S$

then the existence of minimizer follows from the following argument: take a sequence $\{u_n\}$ such that $J(u_n)\to \inf_{u\in S} J(u)$. Then, this sequence is bounded (in the $W^{1,2}(D)$ norm), and thus (by the weak compactness of the $W^{1,2}(D)$ unit ball) there exists a weakly converging subsequence $u_{n_k}\to^w u_0$. Then, by [Mazur's Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mazur%27s_lemma), certain convex combinations of $u_{n_k}$'s (which also lie in $S$) converges strongly to $u_0$, and thus $u_0$ is a minimizer.

Unfortunately, I am unable to prove both (1) and (2).

Comment: For (1): use Poincare inequality. Assumption (2) is not needed to prove existence, it is a consequence of the existence proof.

Comment: Also an assumption is needed on $g,\psi$. There is nothing to guarantee that $S$ is non-empty. $g$ has to be the trace of an $W^{1,2}$ function.